# Plotting with data limits(python)

Tags: python, seaborn

i want plot like this , iam not sure how to set the UL and LL on Y-axis as shown in the below graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxukQ.png)

please help to set limits , i use seaborn package .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chart is called control chart and it can be done using library `pyspc` install it using `pip install pyspc`

You can use these two line to be added for show one limit

```
horiz_line_data = nnp.array([5 for i in range(len(x))])
plt.plot(x, horiz_line_data, 'r--')
```

Here is sample code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nnp
import seaborn as sns
from pyspc import *
sns.set()
plt.figure()
plt.plot([30, 50, 20, 10, 60])
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
LL=5
UL=75
horiz_line_data = nnp.array([LL for i in range(len(x))])
plt.plot(x, horiz_line_data, 'r--')
horiz_line_data = nnp.array([UL for i in range(len(x))])
plt.plot(x, horiz_line_data, 'r--')
plt.ylim((-10, 90))
```

The chart will look like
[image]

Comment: Please make it useful also so that other can benifit

Comment: could you share documentation of PySpc library , i didn't find tutorial of PySpc on internet

Comment: You can find the details here https://github.com/carlosqsilva/pyspc

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
plt.figure()
plt.plot([30, 50, 20, 10, 60])
plt.ylim((-100, 100))
```

[image: Example graph with manually set $Y$ limits]

Comment: Thank you for helping . actually i want to add limits to the y-axis(LL and UL), there should be 2 limits lets say LL=0 and UL=50, these 2 lines also should be visible on plot

Comment: See the other solution. LL and UL will always be there